# Unable to comment on my own question after it was migrated/moved

Tags: support, migration, user-accounts, association

I [posted a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801796/how-to-know-who-is-accessing-my-system-closed) which was then migrated to Server Fault.

Following the move, I found that I was unable to comment or even edit it. Even though I had asked it.

I created an account on Server Fault but was still unable to claim it as my own.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Thanks, i will post there. Hope some big guy can close this here, before i get another -10 votes.

Comment: You must be using Google as your OpenID provider: Top seller! Will associate accounts again, A+++++.

Comment: You'll need to create and associate account here on meta too

Answer (score 5):

When you make a ServerFault account, it asks if you want to associate your account from StackOverflow. You need to do that so the system knows it's you.

Either that, or just ask your question again there.

Comment: "ask your question again" is a **bad** idea.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem, and I was using Google OpenID and my accounts were associated (I know they were, because I got the +100 rep).  Even then, I could not modify or delete my own comment.  In fact, I could up-vote it if I wanted!  I ended up just flagging it so someone else would remove it.