# Cannot follow up on my own migrated question

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, user-accounts

- [Cannot comment on my own question and its answers after it was migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126265) - this is similar, but not the problem that I have.
- [Unable to comment on my own question after it was migrated/moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31009) - almost it, except for the part that I do have a StackExchange account and all my accounts on StackExchange-related sites are connected (associated) with each other.

Here's my original question: https://serverfault.com/questions/526385

---

More details on what exactly happened:

- I have an account on serverfault.com, but I don't have an account on unix.stackexchange.com. After I saw that the question was migrated, I followed the link and ran into some SO error (your typical ASP.NET error page telling you that something went wrong).
- I've reloaded the page and was able to create an account using Google OpenID (that's the same mechanism I use for my other accounts on StackExchange).
- Now, each time that I'm trying to visit Unix&Linux forum, I'm getting a technical error from StackExchange, if I am at the same time logged with Google OpenID. Otherwise, I can see the question, but since I'm not logged as the author of the question, I cannot comment or reply to other commenter.

---

I believe this must be some StackExchange bug, but I could be wrong.

Comment: This didn't happen with me when my first question was migrated to [webmasters.SE] and I'd to register there.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I don't think it should happen, but there seems to be an error on the implementation level, not on the logistics layer. I.e. something crashes in the code that is supposed to log me in. I'll post a screenshot to make it more clear.

Comment: Hm... weird, I no longer get the earlier error, but my question now doesn't belong to me (I cannot comment on it).

Answer (score 2):

I saw there were some problems with your account in the exception log last night, and I attempted to fix everything up.  While I think I got everything, I might have missed the migrated question's ownership issue.

It looks like everything is good now, though - are you still unable to comment on your Unix & Linux question?

Comment: Nope, I cannot comment, though it is "sensible" in a way: I don't have enough karma points. And I don't own the question any longer, but that's fine, I suppose, I won't be missing it much :) Eventually I solved the problem already anyway :)

Comment: Hmmm, is [this user](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/43851/wvxvw) not your user?  If not, can you provide me a link to the user you're logged in as, please?

Comment: If that is your user, and you own that post, *and* you cannot comment, it is a sign of a deeper bug.

Comment: That is my user indeed, however the user who posted the question "isn't" me :) the edits on the question appear as if they were made by someone else, i.e. as if two people edited the question, while it was me all the time :)

Comment: Oh, disregard that last message. Apparently, it's fixed now. Could be some cookie-caching-race thing. It seems to be all good now.